# Pre-populate HTML content in the Page Content field of custom Article Page layout?

Tags: page-layout, publishing-page

I have a custom content type, say "MyCompany Article Page" inheriting from standard "Article Page" content type. In my associated custom publishing layout, how do i pre-populate some HTML rich content in the "Page Content" field?
I'm looking for a way to do this in Design Manager, SharePoint 2013. I created the custom page layout using Design Manager.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible to do from your custom page layout HTML file, but requires some jiggery-pokery to work properly.

If you navigate to the Page Content Snippet in your HTML page, you can add html by editing the following line:

```
<!--MS:<PageFieldRichHtmlField:RichHtmlField FieldName="f55c4d88-1f2e-4ad9-aaa8-819af4ee7ee8" runat="server">-->
```

simply edit it like so:

```
<!--MS:<PageFieldRichHtmlField:RichHtmlField FieldName="f55c4d88-1f2e-4ad9-aaa8-819af4ee7ee8" runat="server" Html="This is my HTML">-->
```

Note, however, that this will only accept text, if you try to add `<h3>` or other bracketed code, it will break the input, as < & > are used as code delimiters in Sharepoint.  To get around this, you need to write:

`<` as `&lt;` and `>` as `&gt;`

This way the code `<h2>Header</h2>` becomes `&lt;h2&gt;Header&lt;/h2&gt;`

While this is a bit awkward and long-handed, it is the method I use to directly implement templates into a custom publishing page content snippet.

Comment: Just comment that the char `"` has to be replaced by `&#34;` as well

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you simply need to set a default value for your Rich Text field. This cannot be done from the UI, but can easily be achieved by PowerShell: see for instance http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28386.powershell-to-set-up-default-value-for-rich-text-field-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx.

The PowerShell code would be like:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb <Absolute-URL-of-Root-Site>
$f = $web.Fields["<FieldInternalName"]
$f.DefaultValue = "<YOUR HTML STRING>"
$f.Update()
```

Comment: actually here is the scenario, I've 3 types of News Content Type. Event,Communication and Company News. Each Content Type inherit from Article Page. Now "Page Content" which is a Publishing HTML type, I want different dafault content with different content for Event, Communication and Company in this field. I cannot stick default content in the generic Site Column - "Page Content" as i want it to change based on the Content Type.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a workflow in SharePoint Designer to set the field on that content type when the document is created.

Comment: Please, please, please, no big/buggy/slow/heavy/UI-visible workflows for such a technical task... Workflows (technical) are for workflows (functional)... at the best.

Comment: Not everyone (including me) has powershell access.