# After New Form route user to defined page

Tags: list, list-view, list-form, newform

I want to integrate a new form from a custimized SP list in a web page. But after submit the form I don't want that the user will route to the list.

I want to define what the user will see after sumbit the form.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the URL of the page where you want your users to navigate after saving the form in the `Source` query parameter.

Like below:

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Lists/listName/NewForm.aspx?Source=<redirection-page-url>
```

Check below references for more information:

1. [Customize newform save button - Save and redirect to another form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153673/customize-newform-save-button-save-and-redirect-to-another-form)
2. [Sharepoint List after saving redirect to custom page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe93d085-20fd-45c6-a5f4-2699dabf6cbf/sharepoint-list-after-saving-redirect-to-custom-page)

If that doesn't work for you then try below:

[How To Redirect Different Page On Save Button Click On SharePoint Forms Using Client Side Script](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-redirect-different-page-on-save-button-click-on-sharepoint-forms-using-client-side-script/)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much again.

Comment: You're welcome. Please [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.